# How do I add characters in print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

I would like the output of the following function to have a "|" character at the beginning and another "|" at the end without adding spaces. How do I add these 2 characters to the final print statement?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


zipCode = raw_input("Enter a zipcode: ")

def printBarCode(zipCode):
    a = 0
    total = sum(map(int,str(zipCode)))
    if total <= 10:
            a= 10-total
    elif total <= 20:
            a = 20-total
    elif total <= 30:
            a = 30-total
    elif total <= 40:
            a = 40-total
    elif total <= 50:
            a = 50-total
    checkDigit= str(a)

    codes={1:":::||",2:"::|:|",3:"::||:",4:":|::|",5:":|:|:",6:":||::",7:"|:::|",8:"|::|:",9:"|:|::",0:"||:::"}

    List = []

    for letter in zipCode:
            List.append(codes[int(letter)])

    for i in checkDigit:
            List.append(codes[int(i)])
    print ''.join(List)

printBarCode(zipCode)
```

Comment: Just append and prepend your characters in List before `print` statement

Comment: @Dheerendra is there a way to do it with print formating?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Use string formatting with print

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "|{}|".format(''.join(List))
```